# Managing iphone and android projects

Tags: android, iphone

What remote tools can be used to manage android and iphone/ipad? Should I used my own server to manage the projects remotely, or buy specific software to manage the projects remotely?  I also would like for my clients to have access to review the status of my projects 24/7, and also have my small team store the current version of code on the server or remote software in case a developer leaves the project.  Thanks everyone for your help in advance! I know these are some long questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with using a hosting service then a cloud service like GitHub might be worth investigating.
If you want full controll the you could set up a git repository on your server.
If your developers use AIDE on Android devices then it supports git version controll.
This will only provide you with source control though.

Br,
Arne